# How can JSON response be stored in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json

What I need:

- all JSON data stored in `localStorage`.

My JS code so far:

```
for (var x = 0; x < parsed.length; x++) {

  var objs = parsed[x];
  console.log(objs);
  // console above json string prints.

  var ajaxData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ajaxData'));

if (ajaxData == null) {
    ajaxData = [];
  }

  var details = {};
  details["id"] = id;
  details["eventname"] = eventname;
  details["city"] = city;
  details["country"] = country;
  details["event_url"] = event_url;
  details["month"] = month;
  details["day"] = day;

  ajaxData.push(details);

  localStorage.setItem('ajaxData', JSON.stringify(ajaxData));
  var EventDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.ajaxData);
  console.log(EventDetails);
```

The problem is:

- when refreshing page the same data is displayed over and over again.
- I suppose my storing mechanism or JSON serialization is wrong.

Comment: The actual JSON is irrelevant as long as it is valid JSON. Your problem is in the code, not the data. When you post on SO you should minimize the clutter and be relevant. Please review the guidelines for posting questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `details` you don't get the data out of the `objs`. This may be a step forward:

```
var i, objs, ajaxData, details, debugDetails;

for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++)
{
  objs = parsed[i];
  console.log(objs); // debug print-out of JSON content

  ajaxData = localStorage.ajaxData;

  if (ajaxData === null)
  {
    ajaxData = [];
  } else {
    ajaxData = JSON.parse(ajaxData); // only if it is valid JSON
  }

  // exclude from local storage irrelevant data
  details = {
    "id": objs.id,
    "eventname": objs.eventname,
    "city": objs.city,
    "country": objs.country,
    "event_url": objs.event_url,
    "month": objs.month,
    "day": objs.day
  };

  ajaxData.push(details);
  localStorage.ajaxData = JSON.stringify(ajaxData);

  debugDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.ajaxData);
  console.log(debugDetails); // debug print-out of stored details
```

Does this work?

I've also replaced major parts of your syntax:

- variables are hoisted to the top, there is no such thing as local variables in JS;
- you can setup and object the way shown here, it's more convenient then setting all properties separately;
- `localStorage` can be used as shown, it is the standard way of using it (instead of `getItem()`/`setItem()`).

If this does not work as intended I'll dig deeper. Let me know.

By further optimizing your code this is the result:

```
var i, ajaxData;

for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++)
{
  ajaxData = localStorage.ajaxData;
  ajaxData = ajaxData === null ? [] : JSON.parse(ajaxData);

  ajaxData.push({
    "id": parsed[i].id,
    "eventname": parsed[i].eventname,
    "city": parsed[i].city,
    "country": parsed[i].country,
    "event_url": parsed[i].event_url,
    "month": parsed[i].month,
    "day": parsed[i].day
  });

  localStorage.ajaxData = JSON.stringify(ajaxData);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var details = {};
  details["id"] = "id";
  details["eventname"] = "eventname";
  details["city"] = "city";
  details["country"] = "country";
  details["event_url"] = "event_url";
  details["month"] = "month";
  details["day"] = "day";

    // Put the object into storage
    localStorage.setItem('storeObject', JSON.stringify(details));

    // Retrieve the object from storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('storeObject');

    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```